# Building a SWC from IntelliJ Idea without resorting to ant?

Tags: apache-flex, intellij-idea, swc

First, here's what I want to do:

```
* Compile my library code into a SWC
* Do not staticly link the Flex framework
```

At first, I tried just setting up a Flex module, clicking the "library" and "use framework as an RSL" buttons. This however doesn't compile any of my code into the SWC, and it basically just compiles a new SWC of the entire Flex framework, all resources and classes included.

Then, I managed to get my classes into the build using a custom compiler config, but it still includes the few Flex classes that I reference in my library code.

Finally, I figured I could use the custom flex-config.xml file, remove the parent reference to the library using `<library-path append="false"></library-path>` and then using a custom command line parameter (and also from ant), add `-compiler.external-library-path` references to the SDK and PlayerGlobal.swc. This should probably work, but Idea won't let me set command line parameters when I'm using a custom config file :'(

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, Through help on the Idea forums, much googling, and random experimentation, here's what worked. Take careful note that some parameters are specified like "{name}" and some are "${name}". No, I don't know why :-/

```
<!-- Specifies the minimum player version that will run the compiled SWF. -->
<!-- 9.0.124 is the April 2008 security release -->
<target-player>9.0.124</target-player>

<compiler>

    <source-path>
        <path-element>src</path-element>
    </source-path>

    <incremental>true</incremental>

    <keep-as3-metadata append="true">
        <name>Inject</name>
        <name>InjectInto</name>
        <name>InjectIntoContents</name>
        <name>Singleton</name>
        <name>PostConstruct</name>
    </keep-as3-metadata>

    <!-- Remove the "include" library path. -->
    <library-path append="false"></library-path>

    <!-- Set up an "external library" path that is compiled against but not linked. -->
    <!-- SWCs not used for SP are left in but commented out to make it easier to copy this script -->
    <external-library-path>
        <path-element>${flexlib}/libs/player/{targetPlayerMajorVersion}/playerglobal.swc</path-element>
        <path-element>${flexlib}/libs/framework.swc</path-element>
        <!--<path-element>${flexlib}/libs/flex.swc</path-element>-->
        <!--<path-element>${flexlib}/libs/rpc.swc</path-element>-->
        <!--<path-element>${flexlib}/libs/utilities.swc</path-element>-->
        <!--<path-element>${flexlib}/libs/datavisualization.swc</path-element>-->
    </external-library-path>

</compiler>

<static-link-runtime-shared-libraries>false</static-link-runtime-shared-libraries>

<include-classes>
    <class>net.expantra.smartypants.impl.InjectorImpl</class>
</include-classes>

<output>./build/SmartyPants-IOC.swc</output>
```